# Java Servlet interface is expected here

Tags: java, servlets

I am absolutely new to Java.

I am creating a Servlet and getting the error `interface is expected here.`

Can you please make me understand the problem(s)?

I am using IntelliJ 14.

My Servlet code is as follows:-

```
package ERPdetector;  

/** 
 * Created by Sinha on 12/15/14. 
 */  

import javax.servlet.http.*;  
import javax.servlet.*;  
import java.io.*;  

public class ErpServlet implements HttpServlet {  

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)  
            throws ServletException,IOException  
    {  
        res.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();  

        String dropdown=req.getParameter("dropdown");  
        pw.println("You Requested for "+dropdown);  

        pw.close();  
    }  
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpServlet` is an abstract class, not an interface - `Servlet` is an interface, but you rarely implement that directly.

Just change this:

```
public class ErpServlet implements HttpServlet {
```

to

```
public class ErpServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `implements` keyword only when you are implementing an `interface` since `HttpServlet` is an `abstract class` you should use `extends` keyword.

Since you are trying to use `implements` keyword for an `abstract` class (HttpServlet), your IDE is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

HttpServlet is a class which implements Servlet. So you have to extends HttpServlet class, Or you have to implements Servlet interface. And do the Http related stuff manually.

HttpServlet has already override the methods from Servlet interface. It has doGet,doPost,doPut like methods. If you want to implement Servlet interface then you have to override all the interface method and handles HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse objects.

Comment: can you describe this part **So you have to extends HttpServlet class, Or you have to implements Servlet interface. And do the Http related stuff manually.**

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPServlet` isn't an interface. Please follow [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm) to get your servlet working.

If you want to use your own implementation of [`HTTPServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) class, then please create a replica of the original abstract class i.e. implement intefaces [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) and [`ServletConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html) as well as extend [`GenericServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html).

If you want to use [`SipServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19355-01/820-3007/gfmqz/index.html), you got to implement the same interfaces as in the [`SipServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss40/javadoc/jsr289/javax/servlet/sip/SipServlet.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Implements  --> Interface and 
Extends --> Class or Abstract class.

so you have used implements keyword instead of extends. just replace the below line in your code.

public class ErpServlet **extends** HttpServlet

Thanks